# How does diff treat merge commits in JGit

Tags: git, jgit

I'm trying to programmatically find the diff between two commits using JGit lib.

Suppose I have the following commit hierarchy:

```
---1---2---3---4---5---6---7---8--
        \--9-—10—-11--/
```

Now let's say I'm analyzing the diffs between commits 4 - 7, how will the diff command refer to the merge in 6?
will it hold information relevant to previous commits (prior to 4), such as 2?

I'm using the following code to determine the diffs:

```java
private static List<DiffEntry> getDiffsBetweenCommits(String repositoryWorkDir, String fromCommit, String toCommit) {
    List<DiffEntry> diffs = null;
    try {

        // Access GIT repository
        File workDir = new File(repositoryWorkDir);
        Git git = Git.open(workDir);
        repository =  git.getRepository();

        // Locate commit references
        ObjectId current = repository.resolve(toCommit + "^{tree}");
        ObjectId previous = repository.resolve(fromCommit + "^{tree}");

        // Generate tree iterators
        ObjectReader reader = git.getRepository().newObjectReader();
        CanonicalTreeParser oldTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
        oldTreeIter.reset(reader, previous);
        CanonicalTreeParser newTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
        newTreeIter.reset(reader, current);

        // Calculate GIT differences
        diffs = git.diff()
                .setNewTree(newTreeIter)
                .setOldTree(oldTreeIter)
                .call();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error analyzing commit's diffs");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return diffs;
}
```

It I'm getting files changed in commits that are far older than 4, and I suspect that I get them because of the merging / rebasing history, but I don't understand it well enough so I'll be able to explain it to myself.

Appreciate your assistance in understanding the diff analysis logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better off rephrasing/this question to put it in the more general Git context.

Nonetheless, here is what I know about the topic: Unlike other SCMs, Git stores the full contents of a commit, not just the diff to the parent commit. Each commit references a so-called 'tree' that lists all the files within the commit along with pointers to the respective file content.

When a commit is created, the tree of its parent is taken, all staged changes (add, modify, remove) are applied and the resulting (new) tree is stored along with the commit metadata. Regarding its content, each commit can be reconstructed without referring to its parent(s).

Let's assume that each of the commits in your example added a single unique file. If you look at commit #6, it contains all files from 1 to 6, plus those of 9, 10, 11. And consequently, 'git diff 4 6' will compare the tree of commit #4 with the tree of commit #6 (which includes all files in your history thus far).

For more details about storage internals in Git, you may want to read this article: http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/10/20/git-internals/ The post is accompanied by self-contained learning tests to examine the results with JGit.